# Game synchronisation in peer-to-peer online multiplayer game

Tags: networking, multiplayer, mobile, peer-to-peer

I am developing an `online real-time multiplayer game using Google Play Game Service and Cocos2D-X`. The game has two players where each player control their own ball.

The each player sends their `own ball’s velocity and position` to the other connected device. In my game, all the physics calculations are done `locally on each devices` i.e. ball velocities after physical calculations are calculated locally on each devices.

**Issue**:

When fast moving ball collides wth the opponent’s ball, there is `no change in the movement velocity` of the opponent’s ball. (According to real world physics, the fast moving ball should be able to push the opponent’s slowly moving ball.)

**Reason:**

During my code analysis, I understood that the velocity calculated by the local physics engine are overwritten by the data received from the opponent’s device.

For e.g.
[image]

**Solution I tried:**

To fix the problem, whenever the collision between balls occurs I am creating one of the device as server and other device as client. All the physics calculations occurs on the server device and data is send to the client device.

**I have following questions:**

1. Is the solution tried by me is optimal solution to fix the issue?
2. What other approaches can be tried to fix such type of issue?

   I would appreciate any suggestions/thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: My colleague Matt Delbosc gave a great talk at GDC this year about [how this was addressed for peer-to-peer vehicle collisions in Watch Dogs 2](http://gdcvault.com/play/1024010/Replicating-Chaos-Vehicle-Replication-in). The video is unfortunately members-only content on the Vault at present, but [the PDF of the slides is free](http://twvideo01.ubm-us.net/o1/vault/gdc2017/Presentations/Matt_Delbosc_Replicating_Chaos.pdf).